# Ajax displaytag in webmail application example

Tags: frameworks, stripes

I have problem after putting in the filter ajax function to the webmail 
application example in the Stripes book. When I click column header to sort 
the table records, it works. However, when I filter the table records by using 
the filter function and then click the column header to sort the filtered 
table records, it gives the correct results but only the table portion and 
layout without table lines and colour like not using css stylesheet. Please 
advice. Thank you in return.